# How to read tag values from XML from server directly in java?

Tags: java, xml, networking

I get XML file on server "localhost:7878" as shown in image. I have to read tag values from there. Highlighted part changes every second. Currently I'm parsing XML file and reading it. Is there any better way where I directly get tag values?
[image]

Comment: If the server only gives you that XML file, you have no option but to parse it. Are you using DOM or SAX?

Comment: currently I'm using DOM. Is there any better way?

Comment: If you're only interested in those specific parts, SAX would be a more obvious choice. It wouldn't make a significant difference, but it would still be faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: Will it be able to 'listen' changes in tag values?

Comment: No, since the server doesn't have a way of notifying you (I assume), you can only poll the server for changes. This applies to every choice you have, whether you use SAX, JAXB, DOM, StaX or any other technology. If the server doesn't want you to know about the changes, then you won't know.

Comment: Suppose server has a way to notify? what are options for notifying?

Comment: Does the server have a way? Are you responsible for the server code?

Comment: no. Not exactly. Some other program is writing on this server in standard XML format. We are just reading it.

Comment: Then you're stuck with XML and polling, sorry.

Comment: Is there any kind of event listener which we can ask server to implement?

Comment: No. If you were in charge of the server you could make a socket connection there, have the server output modified values when they come up, and just keep the connection open. But if you're not writing the server **then you're stuck with XML and polling**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java).

Off the top of my head, the expression for timestamp is

```
//Execution/@timestamp
```

and HIGHACTIVE text node:

```
//Execution/text()
```

Comment: Will it be able to 'listen' changes in tag values?

Comment: no, it's just a way to access elements in XML, not an event listener

Comment: Are there any event listener available for this?

Comment: As others have said, you'll need to poll the server at regular intervals to check for changes. HTTP does not provide a way for the server to push updates to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Using jaxb, it will convert XML to java objects http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Values in tag are changing after few seconds. How do I get to know that?

Comment: *from the link example* `Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);` put that in a for loop

Comment: Will it be able to 'listen' changes in tag values?